# java call method dnamicall with a dynamic number of parameters

Tags: java

I am looking at this question

[How do I invoke a Java method when given the method name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string)

and applying what the fist answer says

This is my code to call a method dyanmically, and its argument is an array of string

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
                    try {
                        String [] requiredParameters = testService.getRequiredParameters();
                        String [] parameters = new String[requiredParameters.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i<requiredParameters.length ; i++){
                            String valueRequiredParameter = request.getParameter(requiredParameters[i]);
                            parameters[i] = valueRequiredParameter;
                        }
                          method = new TestRecommendations().getClass().getMethod(service, parameters);
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {
                          // exception handling omitted for brevity
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                          // exception handling omitted for brevity
                        }
```

i get compiler error  on the `getMethod` states :

```
The method getMethod(String, Class<?>...) in the type Class<capture#1-of ? extends TestRecommendations> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String[])
```

And this is the type of method i want to call dynamcially

```
public ResultSet level0ForUser(String ... userURI) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the method with something like:

```
Method m = TestRecommendations.class.getMethod("level0ForUser", String[].class);
```

And invoke like:

```
m.invoke(new TestRecommendations(), new Object[] { new String[]{ "A", "B", "C" } } );
```

Answer (score 2):

you're passing arguments with the wrong type. Your `getMethod` call accepts one `String` instance and multiple `Class` instances. And you're trying to pass one `String` and `String` array

via [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)):

> `getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)`
>
> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object. The name parameter is a String specifying the simple name of the desired method. The parameterTypes parameter is **an array of Class objects that identify the method's formal parameter types, in declared order.** If parameterTypes is null, it is treated as if it were an empty array.

so you need to pass `Class` var arg which consists of all the arguments types of desired method. For your method you should write something like:

```
Method m = TestRecommendations.class.getMethod("service", String[].class);
```

Comment: Oh okay, so how can I pass the parameters please ?

Comment: where do you pass the `parameters` array? and i do have a specific declaration for my method, as I showed you in the question, my method accepts just an array of string. could you check please ?

Comment: oh, I just didn't get your question, sorry. Fixed

Comment: plus one for the apreciated efforsts